# Windows Azure solr and hadoop data

Tags: azure, solr, hadoop, lucene, lucene.net

Is it possible to Index data residing inside the Hadoop storage on azure using SOLR or lucene ?? The data can consists of anything including pdf,doc,docx etc. How can it be achieved?? I am highly confused. Any guidance help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with Hadoop on Azure.

Basically, you can retrieve each file from HDFS using the following [code](http://blog.rajeevsharma.in/2009/06/using-hdfs-in-java-0200.html).

After, you can don anything with this content, for example indexing in Lucene. For this follow the following [link](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/lucene/index.html)